# How to change color of axes lines in VTK CubeAxesActor2D

Tags: c++, vtk

I'm trying to change the color of the axis lines in a render.

`CubeAxesActor` has `SetZAxesLinesProperty` which accepts `SetColor(0, 1, 1)` but I'm not seeing anything like that in `CubeAxesActor2D`?

http://www.vtk.org/doc/nightly/html/classvtkCubeAxesActor.html
http://www.vtk.org/doc/nightly/html/classvtkCubeAxesActor2D.html

Code that changes the text label color:

```
m_axes->SetAxisTitleTextProperty(SetColor(0, 1, 1));
```

I'm trying something like:

```
m_axes->SetZAxesLinesProperty(SetColor(0, 1, 1));
```

But that function is missing from `CubeAxesActor2D`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you should in another way:

1. vtkCubeAxesActor2D has a method for each axis that return a vtkAxisActor2D

        `vtkAxisActor2D *  GetXAxisActor2D ();`

2. vtkAxisActor2D has a protected attribute that allows acces to the a vtkActor2D
        `vtkActor2D * AxisActor;`

3. The vtkActor2D has a method to access the object properties
        `vtkProperty2D *   GetProperty ();`

4. And finally you can use the method for change the color
        `SetColor (double, double, double);`